# Change image in File type

Tags: javascript, html, image

As we know Below code will take the Image and change it in the file type

```
<input type="file"
       id="avatar" name="avatar"
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

How can I change an image which is in JPG/PNG,in a folder into file type  format using javascript

Comment: Can you elaborate? _"As we know Below code will take the Image and change it in the file type"_ What is a file type? What do you mean? Do you want to convert an image? _"How can I change an image which is in JPG/PNG,in a folder into file type format using javascript"_ What is a file type format?

Comment: If you want to chage the image format, draw the image onto a canvas, and create the conversion using [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method of the canvas.

Comment: actually,I want to change the formate of Image in file type. What it means ,let say we select image,How it store in file formate  
FileList
0: File
lastModified: 1652339334767
lastModifiedDate: Thu May 12 2022 12:38:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name: "After Before 2.jpg"
size: 164196
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: FileList
How can I achive this without Input element ,

Comment: What do you want to change? You selected a JPEG file and the type is `image/jpeg`. Are you asking how to manually create a `File` object? You can use the [`File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

Comment: You can't pick a file from users' local system without `input type="file"` element.

Comment: Are you asking how to manually create a File object? YES

Comment: You can use the [`File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File): https://jsfiddle.net/y5ptqaem/